# Access element on-tap handler from host element on-keypress handler

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am developing a building block element a11y-icon to be used for supporting accessibility. This custom element should provide keyboard event handler when the user presses a key on that icon.

```
<dom-module id="a11y-icon">
    <template>
        <iron-icon icon="{{icon}}" style="{{style}}" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label$="{{description}}" on-keypress="_keyPressHandler"></iron-icon>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "a11y-icon",
        properties: {
            icon: String,
            style: String,
            description: String
        },
        _keyPressHandler: function(event) {
            var code = event.keyCode;
            // accept enter or spacebar key
            if (code == 13 || code == 32) {
                // TODO: call on-tap handler defined in element which uses a11y-icon
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

When a developer uses the a11y-icon element and provides an on-tap handler, I want a11y-icon _keyPressHandler to call that on-tap handler.

```
<a11y-icon class="clickable" icon="icons:close" description="close this item" on-tap="_closeItem">
```

My question is how to invoke element on-tap handler (e.g. _closeItem) from host element handler (e.g. _keyPressHandler)? I assume polymer uses internal data-binding to store on-tap handler somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

By browsing into polymer.html, I finally found a way to invoke on-tap handler inside keypress handler -

```
    _keyPressHandler: function(event) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        // accept enter or spacebar key
        if (code == 13 || code == 32) {
            this.fire("tap", event.currentTarget, event);
        }
    }
```